# Zend Server CE, PEAR Problems, and PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit, pear, zend-server-ce

I have Zend Server CE installed on OS X (10.7.5), I installed PHPUnit via PEAR

```
$ which pear
/usr/local/zend/bin/pear
$which php
/usr/local/zend/bin/php
$php -v
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend Extension Manager v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2003-2013, by Zend Technologies
    - with Zend Data Cache v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2004-2013, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [disabled]
    - with Zend Job Queue v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2004-2013, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [enabled]
    - with Zend Utils v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2004-2013, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [enabled]
    - with Zend Optimizer+ v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [disabled]
    - with Zend Code Tracing v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2009-2013, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [enabled]
    - with Zend Monitor v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [disabled]
    - with Zend Page Cache v6.0.0, Copyright (c) 2004-2013, by Zend Technologies [loaded] [licensed] [disabled]
$ which phpunit
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpunit
```

But when I execute:

```
$ phpunit
```

Inside a test directory (with proper configuration and bootstrapping) I receive the following error:

```
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpunit: line 2: ?php: No such file or directory
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpunit: line 3: /Applications: is a directory
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpunit: line 4: Bootstrap.php: command not found
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpunit: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpunit: line 5: ` * Copyright (c) 2001-2013, Sebastian Bergmann <sebastian@phpunit.de>.'
```

But if I run:

```
$ php /usr/local/zend/bin/phpunit
```

everything works.

Let me expand this a bit:

`which phpdoc` returns `/usr/local/zend/bin/phpdoc` but running `phpdoc` from inside a test folder returns

```
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpdoc: line 2: ?php: No such file or directory
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpdoc: line 3: /Applications: is a directory
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpdoc: line 4: LICENSE.txt: command not found
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpdoc: line 5: LICENSE.txt: command not found
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpdoc: line 6: LICENSE.txt: command not found
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpdoc: line 7: LICENSE.txt: command not found
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpdoc: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/local/zend/bin/phpdoc: line 8: ` * @copyright 2010-2013 Mike van Riel / Naenius (http://www.naenius.com)'
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: what's the first line of that phpunit script file?

Comment: #!/usr/local/zend/bin/php

Comment: try to run `/usr/local/zend/bin/php /usr/local/zend/bin/phpunit`. what do you get?

Comment: When I run your line, everything works. However, if I run `php phpunit` I receive `Could not open input file: phpunit`

Comment: `php phpunit` can never work because php expects a full filename or a file in the current working directory.

Comment: Check original question, not just phpunit, it looks like phpdoc is also being affected